# Is it correct to say "Sweetie, don't stretch the neckline all the way to show off your shoulders like those girls on TV like that"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Some young women wear some special type of tops like the above picture. The top could be a sweater or Tshit or any top can be made into it.

**What is the common term for it in everyday conversation, for example, "*she is wearing an off-shoulder top*"?**

Second, these women may influence your daughters as well.

Say, you have a 4 year-old daughter. She is wearing a normal Tshirt but then she wanted to copy these above women. That is **she stretched the neckline of her Tshirt all the way to show her shoulders visibly to people around her**.

Is it correct to say "**Sweetie, don't stretch the neckline all the way show off your shoulders like those girls on TV like that**"?

is "**show off**" used correctly here?

Comment: _Like that_ is unnecessary, as you have already said _like those girls_.

Comment: That's a *tube top*. If you like shoulders, see also *halter top*.

Answer (score 1):

"Off-the-shoulder" is a good way to describe the sweater in the picture.

For the advice to a daughter, you don't need to put everything in one package.  Lots of your questions ask for a way to say something but assume that the other person doesn't exist and won't respond.

Instead you can just say "Sweetie, don't stretch your tee-shirt."

She then responds.  She might say "okay" or she might say "why" or she might say "I'm not stretching it" or she might say "aww daaaad" or something else.  And then you have a conversation.  You respond to her, and so on.

"show off" is correct, if you think she is really "showing off" her shoulders.  But at age 4 I doubt it. She's just stretching her teeshirt because she can.

Language is meant to be an exchange.  It isn't like a guided missile that you launch at someone and then leave!

Comment: I am pretty sure that little girl was trying to show off her shoulders like in the cartoon.

Comment: And it is idiomatic to say "that girl showed off her legs / shoulders / belly / etc", right?

Comment: I agree with James that the little girl may well be imitating the picture without any understanding of the significance of an adult woman uncovering her shoulders (or any other part). Yes, you can use _showed off_ if it is really being done on purpose.